Can I travel outside the UK when I am waiting for my US B2 visa appointment date?
I am not a UK national. I am applying for US B2 visa. My visa interview appointment date is as far as away as December 2024.
My question is: Can I travel outside the UK between now and December 2024?
If I can travel outside the UK between now and December 2024, then what happens to the international travel history that I have submitted in my DS-160 form? Do I need to have that travel history updated again? Doesn't that require submitting a new DS-160 form and getting a new visa interview appointment date?
I'd like to know what the correct process is in this case from others who have been in a similar situation.

I don't have experience with applying specifically in the UK, but when applying for a US visa in other countries, I was able to submit a new DS-160 form without changing the appointment date.

Recently, while preparing for a visa appointment abroad, I encountered an issue regarding "material changes." These changes, such as job experience and travel history, are crucial when filling out visa applications, especially if you've recently visited a country like Iran, as they could impact the outcome of your application.
The key question is whether you can travel abroad simply with your passport. Yes, you can, but if adding a country to your application constitutes a material change that could affect the outcome, you should update your DS160 form accordingly.
Updates to your situation can happen quickly, so it's essential to keep your DS160 current. Failure to do so could work against you. In my case, I created a new application form to reflect my updated travel plans and history. Fortunately, I was able to update my details at the biometric center without needing to book new appointments.
For those in the UK, the US embassy's official link clearly states that you can amend your DS160 and bring the updated version to the embassy without needing to book a new appointment.

Sure, here's a more detailed explanation of the process:

Traveling outside the UK: You are allowed to travel outside the UK while your US B2 visa application is pending. However, it's crucial to keep track of your international travel history during this time.

Updating DS-160 form: If you travel outside the UK, you'll need to update your DS-160 form with the new travel information. You can access and update your DS-160 form on the US Department of State's Consular Electronic Application Center (CEAC) website.

Submitting a new DS-160 form: Log in to the CEAC website using your application ID, and navigate to the DS-160 form you previously submitted. Update the form with your recent international travel history and any other changes, such as updated contact information or employment details.

No need to change appointment date: You do not need to change your visa interview appointment date when updating your DS-160 form. Simply submit the updated form online.

Printing confirmation page: After you have successfully updated your DS-160 form, print the new confirmation page with the barcode. This updated confirmation page will reflect the changes you made to your travel history.

Bringing updated documents to the interview: When attending your visa interview, make sure to bring the updated DS-160 confirmation page along with any other required documents. This ensures that your application is complete and up to date.


By following these steps, you can ensure that your US B2 visa application accurately reflects your international travel history, even if you travel outside the UK before your visa interview date.
Yes, you can travel outside the UK between now and December 2024. However, if you do, it's important to update your international travel history in your DS-160 form accordingly. You can submit a new DS-160 form without changing your visa interview appointment date. This ensures that your information is up to date for the visa application process.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@zesh - AI generated posts need to be highlighted as such, so readers know to look for the typical issues/mistakes/problems LLMs produce
